# How to free Package or Plan in DB2?

Tags: db2, mainframe

I have a request to retire all the programs which are accessing retired DB2 tables. After retiring all the PLI programs, it is required to delete/free the package or plan.

Will anyone please assist me to free/delete the package or plan. What are the commands or techniques to achieve it?

Comment: Have you asked the DBAs at your site?

Answer (score 0):

The basic DB2 FREE PLAN and FREE PACKAGE commands are available in the DB2 Command Reference which gives you many examples of syntax. 
However, I would suggest that this action is going to be the responsibility of the DBA's at your site, rather than something a programmer/developer would or should do.
If you have no need for any plans or packages, and they truly are obsolete, probably the safest, and easiest way to have them freed is to give a list of them to your DBA team and ask them to do it for you.